# Sharepoint 2010: best practice to migrate legacy data to sharepoint list

Tags: list, migration, sharepoint-2010

I have to migrate some legacy data from stand-alone sql server database to sharepoint list.

I'm going to use programmatic approach and write a code that communicates with sharepoint list asmx web service.

Are there some "data transformation wizards" to simplify such a task or a better approach to port legacy data from sql server database to sharepoint list?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? SQL Server 2008 R2 has SSIS support for SharePoint lists?

Comment: It's usefull information but we work with Sql Express at present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being one time operation, I would not worrry about Best Practice but would consider what's the fastest way to do it.

You can use Excel 2010 (I have not tested it with Excel 2007) export data to Sharepoint 2010. Here are the high level steps:

1. Import data from SQL Server using DATA Tab in the ribbon
2. Excel would automatically create a TABLE
3. Now you can prepare the data for Export to Sharepoint. Here, you can remove unwanted columns, add new columns remove unwanted rows, arrange columns etc.
4. While being in the Table, access the "Export Table To Sharepoint List" functionality to publish you data to Sharepoint. More information about this is available at: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/export-an-excel-table-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA010131472.aspx

It is quick! but let;s be aware of the limitations:
1. It cannot publish data to a list which already exists
2. It will not create a content type for the exported list. The columns are directly attached to the list.

If you want greater control over the migration, programming may be the way to go unless someone has a better idea in this great forum!

Comment: Thank you for the reply it was usefull. I'll pay attention to Office products

Comment: Passing data through Excel, or even Access, can sometimes result in data translation problems as the data types and field lengths may not always match - so VERIFY whether or not data is being lost or truncated.